# Can't I use TensorFlowLite in ios watch app?

Tags: swift, tensorflow, apple-watch, tensorflow-lite, watchos

I am trying to use tensorflowlite by importing into ios watch app. However, this error occurs when I try to install'TensorFlowLiteSwift' using cocoapods.

---

[!] The platform of the target `myapp WatchKit Extension` (watchOS 2.0) is not compatible with `TensorFlowLiteSwift (2.3.0)`, which does not support `watchOS`.

---

I am not sure if tensorflowlite can be used in the current watch app because there is no content on the watch app even if I refer to the official documentation.

Any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: As you noticed, the TensorFlowLite CocoaPods package is only compatible with iOS, and not watchOS or tvOS, etc. Could you share what you wanted to do with TFLite in your watch app?

Comment: Thank yyoon for information I tried to run [speech commnads example](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/speech_commands/ios) on the watch app. I guess I need to find another way.